# VirtManager 0.95 or 0.10 on Ubuntu and "cannot import name GtkVnc"

Tags: 12.04, virt-manager

Anybody knows about this startup error with VirtManager 0.9.5 or 0.10.0 on Ubuntu? "cannot import name GtkVnc" How to fix? What is the cause?

Comment: Do you have gir1.2-gtk-vnc-2.0 installed?

Comment: Could you write some more context? What were you trying to do? where are you seeing this?

Comment: First, sorry, typo - it's virt-manager 0.9.5 or 0.10.0.

Comment: First, sorry, typo - it's virt-manager 0.9.5 or 0.10.0. Okay, Jason: No, I hadn't. Thanks! Installing... I've just tried and got another error - 'init() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)'. I have tried with both 0.9.5 and 0.10.0. Braiam: I want to upgrade virt-manager to the latest version.

Comment: Braiam: I was trying to start virt-manager in both cases and received this error- Error starting Virtual Machine Manager: init() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./virt-manager", line 303, in <module>
    main()
  File "./virt-manager", line 276, in main
    LibvirtGLib.init(None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: init() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with virt-manager 0.10.0 and ubuntu 12.04.3 x64 (I have gir1.2-gtk-vnc-2.0 ). I downloaded a tar from virt-manager web page, unpacked and tried to run "./virt-manager" . virt-manager 0.9.1 works.

For me help  editing virt-manager file

line 276
-    LibvirtGLib.init(None)
+    LibvirtGLib.init(0, "")

PLease see more on: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.virt-tools/5642

Comment: Confirmed comment out or change the line with: 
   'LibvirtGLib.init(None)' 
to:
   'LibvirtGLib.init(0, "")'.

It worked for me! Thanks user188867!